# How do I sent an HTTP request which returns the URL?

Tags: python, youtube-api, discord.py

Im trying to figure out how to search for and return a URL for a search term, I'm confused on how to request using python as my program is using discord.py.

What it does so far is that it can only play videos from a direct youtube link by downloading the video with youtube-dl and then converting it to audio with FFmpeg and playing it.
What I am trying to do is support the above mentioned (links) and detect whether the command is run with a link or not, if it's not a link, I would like it to search the term in Youtube using an HTTP request or similar and then return a URL to then be able to download and play it.
Any support on how I would get this to work? So far I have only found solutions in Javascript and I have absolutely no experience with java so I cant implement it.

Comment: Consider looking at [pytube](https://pytube.io/en/latest/user/search.html)

Comment: @WasiMaster Had no idea that existed! Thanks! Will look into this!